# How to run Draco encoder?

Tags: 3d, compression, gltf

I don't know programming but I've read about draco 3d compression and I have 3d models I would like to compress. I'm trying to follow this guide:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/draco-3d/#3

Somehow I managed to install pyhton, cmake and vistual studio to get to step 4. through CMD.

But where do I even write that next line? I have a draco "build" in a folder...

can I do everything through cmd? or is the next step somewhere in visual studio?

Big thanks from big noob.

Comment: Any particular format?  I see you tagged glTF, is the question only about encoding glTF files?

Comment: I clicked everything in VS and it made a debug folder with draco_encoder.exe that was it, I think  it was the debug button but I dont really know. I could then run the command in cmd yay but without ./ and changing my input dir to correct and full one.

Comment: @emackey yes I was trying to encode gltf/glb, I'm now using gltf-pipeline npm module instead, through cmd. Do you mean you can encode other formats with draco aswell? Like I said in OP i'm a total newbie with this, it's 80% luck I got anything working, my general feeling with doing these things are: it's a wonder I can spell my own name.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you wanna compress using draco you can do this way:
go to terminal (if you are on Windows I suggest you to download Git Bash) and clone this repo with this command

`git clone https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline.git`.

Then install Node.js 6.x or later(https://nodejs.org/en)

From the root directory of this repo, run:

```
npm i 
npm run eslint
npm run build-cesium
```

then you can run

```
node ./bin/gltf-pipeline.js -i /complete/path/of/the/model/model.gltf -o /complete/path/of/where/you/wanna/put/the/model/model_draco.gltf --draco.compressionLevel= 10
```

You need to change "/complete/path/of/the/model/" and "/complete/path/of/where/you/wanna/put/the/model/" with your personal path.

Draco compression level [0-10], most is 10,least is 0. A value of 0 will apply sequential encoding and preserve face order. Default is 7.
You can find command-line flags and explanations here:
https://github.com/CesiumGS/gltf-pipeline#command-line-flags